# To filter contents of table column using Open XML

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I need to filter contents of  table column(in MS-word document) using openxml sdk. I am able get table column contents(as string) using  `reference = tablerow.ElementAt<OpenXmlElement>(0).InnerText`

What I need to do is split the content of column into muliple strings for eg: 
column

```
abcd 

efgh
```

I am getting `abcdefgh` in reference using `reference = tablerow.ElementAt<OpenXmlElement>(0).InnerText`

What I need is to split `abcd` and `efgh` into different strings.

This the piece of code which I am using:

```
foreach (Table table in tables)
{
    foreach (TableRow tablerow in table.Descendants<TableRow>())
    {
        reference = tablerow.ElementAt<OpenXmlElement>(0).InnerText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you just want to split up a string into substrings. You can do that by using [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) or [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on the `reference` string that you get from your foreach loop.